# Scheduling tasks with JobIntentSerivce in Oreo

Tags: android, background-service, android-8.1-oreo

I am already despair, for 2 days I am searching how to to schedule service at the **background** for android O and nothing works, once a week same as `Alarm manger`, I read a lot of articles and I think all the solution in JS it were not a lot of questions about it because its new OS and subject.
I know android O doing optimization and kill/destroy the service but I understood if I am scheduling services with JobIntentService it should be working.
Here is my code

**Manifest:**

```
<service
            android:name=".task.UpdateJobScheduler"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

after this i created JobScheduler:

```
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            UpdateJobScheduler.class.getName()))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setMinimumLatency(1000) //just for test the number
            .setOverrideDeadline(3000) //just for test the number
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setPersisted(false);

    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

**JobIntent service**

```
public class UpdateJobScheduler extends JobIntentService {

private final static String TAG = UpdateJobScheduler.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int JOB_ID = 0X32421;

@Inject
AttributesModel attributesModel;
@Inject
CategoriesModel categoriesModel;
private CompositeDisposable disposable;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DaggerUpdateBroadcastReceiverComponent
            .builder()
            .appComponent(((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent())
            .build()
            .inject(this);
    disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    Log.e(TAG, "ON create");
}

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    try {
        if(work.getIntExtra("test",0) == JOB_ID ){
            enqueueWork(context, UpdateJobScheduler.class, JOB_ID, work);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG,"INTENT DATA UPDATE WRONG");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Service collapse");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "working workingg!!!");
}

@Override
public boolean onStopCurrentWork() {
    disposable.clear();
    return super.onStopCurrentWork();
}
```

I try to set the `enqueueWork` at my `JobInfo` class too and it dose not work.
In addition I read about that not necessary to combine JobScheduler and jobIntentService together its possible to schedule the service at the `enqueueWork`, but I really try to find solution that does it and I really didn't found any example that works from google.
At the console I see one time that it works and nothing.